# Tradeoffer with items selected - Steam Web API

Tags: steam

I can't find the documentation for how to send trade offers with the steam web api. Most people says the API doesn't officially support sending trade offers, but I've seen people saying they achieved making trade offers with a post request to 'https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/send'. I've tried all their suggested implementations, however I always get 'null' response with 401 Unauthorized code. I've tried using Postman and the Chrome Extension 'Postman Interceptor' to record the request of a manual trade offer and then replay the same request. This still gives me the 401 error code and null response.

Next I've tried using the Network tab in Chrome and found the specific request for the trade offer. If I make a manual trade offer and then replay the same post XHR request from the chrome developer tools, then I'm able to send the same trade offer multiple times. Howefter if I try to export the request as a cUrl request and import to Postman, then I get the null and 401 response. If any of you know the Chinese website buff.163.com - they somehow managed to create the post request from their website. So you can press a button on their website and directly get a trade offer you need to confirm on your Steam Mobile App. Do any of you know how they achieve this? I could try to add credits to buff and follow their request - this might have some information on how they do it?

Any help is much appreciated!
[image]

Comment: 401 error means you get username/password pair or auth token wrong. How did you include this info into your request?

Comment: Well i dont include the username/password, however i created a post request to tradeoffer/new/send with the parameter 'key' which is my api key. I'll add the post request data to the original question.

Comment: Could it be that some of the requests has to come from a secure Https connection and not my local host?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is asking about the usage of REST APIs and not about the Steam application.